# Проблема с popover bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Берем элемент. меняем ему через js id, после этого пытаемся создать popover по этому id - не создает, в чем возможна причина?

Comment: v3.3.2 bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой  вопрос. Потому что  popover удаляется не сразу, поэтому создаем новый через таймаут. setTimeout(setPopOver, 300, array_over);

Answer (score 0):

Видимо не видно в доме созданного элемента.
Попробуйте забиндить руками через метод `.on`

```
$('parent-selector-created-hands').on('click','[data-toggle="popover"]', function(){
  $(this).popover();
})
```